# Select Query on Azure Mobile Services Table using Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, select, xamarin

I've got to the point where I can insert new records into my database via a test app, but returning a Select query is giving me fits.

Every time I try to implement the sample code found [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-how-to-use-client-library/#selecting)

```
// Select one field -- just the Text
MobileServiceTableQuery<TodoItem> query = todoTable
                .Select(todoItem => todoItem.Text);
List<string> items = await query.ToListAsync();
```

I get "MobileServiceTableQuery does not exist in the current context.", so I know that I am missing something, but I just can't figure out what it is after hours of fighting with the code.

Can someone point me to a sample app or example code that shows how to fully implement this (I'm populating a table view with the result) that is a bit more descriptive so that I can move on with my project?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.aspx)  namespace?

The class you want:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Query/Linq/MobileServiceTableQuery.cs

Comment: Yes, I am.  That is one of the reasons I'm completely confused and looking for a working sample program to see if there is some other oddity that I don't have implemented correctly.

Comment: Can you post a bit more information about what exactly you are trying to accomplish in the question? Are you just trying to pull data from a database?

Comment: @GlobalJim I have a similar question, trying to figure out how to query the table in an Azure Mobile service:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659505/how-to-query-an-azure-mobile-service